# Correct $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{{y^n\over x}{\ln\left({x\over y}\right)}\over (1-xy)\ln(xy)}\mathrm dxdy=-{2(n+1)(n+3)\over (n+2)^3}?$

Tags: integration

Experimental show that $(1)$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{{y^n\over x}{\ln\left({x\over y}\right)}\over (1-xy)\ln(xy)}\mathrm dxdy=-{2(n+1)(n+3)\over (n+2)^3}\tag1$$

$n\ne-2$

How may one verify that $(1)$ is correct?

Comment: Ehh...Somalia??

Comment: I like to see profiles once in a while. I wasn't sure about Somalia...

Comment: You are right I am not somalia

Comment: I thought so...:) You see, once there was a rock band called "Frankie Goes To Hollywood" The singer, Holly Johnson, was once asked "where were you born?". He replied "Khartoum" as he was annoyed by all sorts of questions. He wasn't born there at all. That came into my mind when I saw Somalia...

Comment: What have you attempted? My first temptation would be to enforce the substitutions $x=e^{-u}, y=e^{-v}$, then perform a change of variable in the resulting integral. I do not know at first sight if expanding $\frac{1}{1-xy}$ as a geometric series helps or if it is an unnecessary complication, but it would not be a bad thing to include a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

Because the integrand contains singularities, the integral does not exist.  However, in a certain principal value sense, the following integral is zero by $x \leftrightarrow y$ symmetry arguments: 
$$
P_{xy}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} dx dy \, {\displaystyle{\ln\left({x\over y}\right)}\over (1-xy)\ln(xy)} = 0
$$ 
where $P_{xy}$ means we keep the integration symmetric in x and y (for example, a Riemann sum that samples the unit square symmetrically). For the same reason, your integral is zero when $n=-1$:
$$
P_{xy}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} dx dy \, {\displaystyle\frac{1}{xy}{\ln\left({x\over y}\right)}\over (1-xy)\ln(xy)} = 0
$$
So, your formula is correct for $n=-1$, but not for other values.